# Monitor 'Out of Range' when setting the correct resolution

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

So, I've set up my monitor on my PC, and it started up on a resolution lower than the monitor's: 1280x720, my display is 1600x900, so I went to windows settings to change it to the correct one.

Thing is, the correct resolution keeps displaying a 'Out of Range' error, and only seem to work on lower resolutions that don't fit correctly

Currently I'm trying some safe-mode configs, I initially thought that because I plugged the display after the PC was on, the POST and BIOS setup didn't automatically set the resolution, but I already tried restarting, safe mode, and even direct graphics card settings overrides, but nothing seems to work

Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your machine, there may be a Monitor driver update that may solve the issue. I see Monitor drivers for Lenovo machines.

Comment: I'll try that next then - I keep the graphics card drivers well updated, but i never thought the monitor itself had a driver too!

Comment: It depends on the computer and the manufacturer.

Comment: Alright, updating the monitor drivers didn't seem to work either :/

Comment: I will look around some more but I am not sure of the cause of this issue.

Comment: See if this discussion about monitors and resolution helps you:   .....  https://itstillworks.com/mean-monitor-says-out-range-12106607.html

Comment: Still nothing :/
I guess the only solution now seems to be buying another display.
Weird is that this same monitor worked before on the same PC, this happened after i unplugged and plugged it back on

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you installed the video driver for the GPU? If no, do this.
2. If yes, do a fresh install the latest video driver, it might have become corrupted.
3. Check the refresh rate of the set resolution is also supported.
4. If all fails, try changing the resolution from safe mode.
5. If you have both integrated and dedicated HPU - did you plug your monitor in the internal or external GPU? In which one was it before?

Let me know how it goes, if it didn't work i'll think of some other possible causes.